# How do I use labels in big query queries to track cost?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to track the cost of bigquery queries using the `configuration.labels` attribute on a query request? I have specified some labels and I do find it in the job definition as you can see here:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "labels": {
      "label1": "tomas",
      "label2": "yolo"
    },
    "query": {
      "allowLargeResults": false,
      "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
      "destinationTable": {
        "datasetId": "dataset",
        "projectId": "project name",
        "tableId": "label "
      },
      "priority": "INTERACTIVE",
      "query": "a select query",
      "useLegacySql": false,
      "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
...
}
```

I have also enabled billing export under billing, but when I look at the exported data I can’t find my labels.

Labeling works fine when applied to dataset and tables, but I can't get it to work with queries. Are these labels for queries something else and doesn't show up in the billing?

Comment: Please submit your use case here and any other details https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111024351

Comment: This actually works, but it might take some time for the labels to show up in the exported data.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing where they show up, just curious.

Comment: @Pentium10 screen short is hard to provide since that depends on what you do, but I'll explain. Under billing you can configure export of billing data to bigquery, after you have configured that you should be able to find the labels in one (or more) tables that are exported by that automatic process. We have also configured a datastudio dashboard that reads that data, so if you have that it should show up there as well.

Comment: Update from respective [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111024351) - It seems like the labels work after all, it just took a long time for them to propagate to the exported table. The weird part is that it wasn't exported at the first available export, instead it was exported later in the day.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I would comment in the issue tracker as well.

Comment: @TomasJansson I see in comments that you were successful in adding labels to bigquery tables. I wanted to do the same but programatically. I use Airflow BigqueryOperator for creation of queries and dumping the data to destination table. I am not able to add labels during the creation of table using BigqueryOperator . If you know could you help on that?  [This is the link ] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69992114/add-labels-to-bigquery-tables-using-airflow-bigqueryoperator) to the  options I have tried

Answer (score 3):

You can add querylabels (key:value) by adding the following to your query:

```sql
SET @@query_label = "label_key:label_value";

SELECT *
FROM your_project_id.your_dataset.your_table;
```

This changes the system variable `@@query_label`, see also:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adding-labels#adding-label-to-session
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/system-variables

Setting `@@query_label` will create a parent_job without the `key:value` label, but it will also create a child job that does have the `key:value` label.

You can see that when querying the information schema to get insights into query details (you need approriate authorization to execute this query):

```sql
SELECT creation_time, job_id, parent_job_id, user_email, labels, query, total_bytes_billed
FROM `your_project_id.region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS`
WHERE creation_time >= '2022-12-06'
ORDER BY creation_time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to query or filter on specific labels, but can at least display them with this...

```
SELECT  service.description, cost, labels
FROM `PROJECTNAME.billing_report.gcp_billing_export_v1_016D47_E84908_9F5AB5` 
WHERE cost > 0
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: this is not really what the question is about, but if you want to filter on them you need to `unnest` them.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `bq` command, you can do it by adding `--label` flag as below

```sh
bq query \
--nouse_legacy_sql \
--label foo:bar \
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `bigquery-public-data`.samples.shakespeare'
```

Then, you can issue below filter in Cloud logging

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.labels.foo="bar"
```

For API or Client Library, check this [object](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfiguration)