# Add labels to BigQuery tables using Airflow BigqueryOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have to add labels to the bigquery tables. I am aware of doing it through BigQuery UI but how can it be done through airflow operators.

***Use case*** : For billing and searching purpose. As multiple teams work under same project and dataset, we need to club together all the tables created by respective teams. As each team will have different labels for the tables, hence labels are necessary for us.

```
bq_query = BigQueryOperator(bql=sql,
                            destination_dataset_table='my_dataset.my_table'),
                            task_id='bq_query',
                            bigquery_conn_id='my_bq_connection',
                            use_legacy_sql=False,
                            write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                            create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                            query_params={})
```

Here I want to add label to this destination table `destination_dataset_table='my_dataset.my_table'`

I did give a try as mentioned in this link : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator.template_fields

```
from airflow import models, DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operator, bigquery_to_gcs, bigquery_table_delete_operator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator



# Define Airflow DAG
with dag:

    bq_query = BigQueryOperator(sql='<some query>',
                                destination_dataset_table='my_dataset.my_table'),
                                task_id='bq_query',
                                use_legacy_sql=False,
                                write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                                create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                                labels={'project_id': 'project_name', 'dag_id': 'dag_name', 'task_id': 'task_name'}
                                query_params={})
```

**EDIT**

Note : The definition of `labels`  is different for BigqueryOperator and BigqueryCreateExternalTableOperator as per the documentation.

Definition of labels for BigqueryOperator is `a dictionary containing labels for the job/query, passed to BigQuery` which is happening fine. But I wanted to add a label to the table when it gets created.

We are widely using BigqueryOperator and cannot use BigqueryCreateExternalTableOperator

Is it possible using BigqueryOperator? or a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the class **airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator** you are using, you can use the parameter label. You can see the parameters that supports.

**labels**  – a dictionary containing labels for the job/query, passed to BigQuery

```
classairflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(bql=None, sql=None, destination_dataset_table=None, write_disposition='WRITE_EMPTY', allow_large_results=False, flatten_results=None, bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, udf_config=None, use_legacy_sql=True, maximum_billing_tier=None, maximum_bytes_billed=None, create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED', schema_update_options=, query_params=None, labels=None, priority='INTERACTIVE', time_partitioning=None, api_resource_configs=None, cluster_fields=None, location=None, encryption_configuration=None, *args, **kwargs)
```

You can use this class **airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryCreateExternalTableOpera**tor to create the table with tags

**labels**  – a dictionary containing labels for the table, passed to BigQuery

```
classairflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(bql=None, sql=None, destination_dataset_table=None, write_disposition='WRITE_EMPTY', allow_large_results=False, flatten_results=None, bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, udf_config=None, use_legacy_sql=True, maximum_billing_tier=None, maximum_bytes_billed=None, create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED', schema_update_options=, query_params=None, labels=None, priority='INTERACTIVE', time_partitioning=None, api_resource_configs=None, cluster_fields=None, location=None, encryption_configuration=None, *args, **kwargs)
template_fields= ['bql', 'sql', 'destination_dataset_table', 'labels']
```

You can see more [information](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator.template_fields) about these two classes.

**EDIT**

You can see this example.

```
   bq_query = BigQueryOperator(bql=sql,
                                destination_dataset_table='my_dataset.my_table'),
                                task_id='bq_query',
                                bigquery_conn_id='my_bq_connection',
                                use_legacy_sql=False,
                                write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                                create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                                template_fields= ['dataset_id', 'table_id', 'project_id', 'gcs_schema_object', 'labels']
                                query_params={})
```

You can see this [example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.html#BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator.template_fields) on how to use it.

Comment: Have you tried it before as it does not work for me

Comment: @Neha0908 I update the answer.

Comment: The definition of "labels" of both the above mentioned classes are different. BigQueryOperator  : labels ( dictionary containing labels for the job/query, passed to BigQuery) , BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator : labels(a dictionary containing labels for the table, passed to BigQuery)
I wanted to achieve the latter "label" definition but cannot use "BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator " as we store data in Bigquery Storage and not cloud storage.
Also we create thousand of tables from existing tables and therefore wants to label the tables

Comment: Also the variables inside template_fields have to be defined somewhere. Is that Airflow variables where these should be updated with their proper values.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.  Still I did not see label thing happening on bigquery tables using BigqueryOperator. It id working with BigqueryCreateExternalTableOperator though but that operator I cant use.

Comment: You can use these options for labels  [1]bq (shell command) or [2] bq API to define/implement.

 [1]https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html
  [2]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adding-labels#api